# Alert me How to send data to Sales Force objects from function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I know `we have connector into Logic app to insert data into Sales Force` but is there any `sample code present in c#`

using which we can able to insert data into sales force object using azure function?

I have `json array as output` and its `hard to use for-each and compose` in term of nested logic into logic app.

so i want to use c# code using function app.

Comment: Cause azure doesn't built-in  Sales Force, so you should just use the Salesforce API to do it. Here is the [API link](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp#salesforce-marketing-cloud-fuel-sdk-for-c), and here is a [sample code](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XbCoQAK).

Comment: thank you for link , but unable to figure out there are no apis for update and insert object data into specific sales force custom object based on external id